# Не понимаю почему bash находит ошибку

Tags: linux, bash, компиляция

При выполнении кода когда вводишь 0, выдается ошибка:

./Podsget: line 45: Минимальное: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "Минимальное")

Пробовал искать в 45 строке. но опять таки не пойму в чем ошибка

Вот код:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "введите PREFIX: "
read Slov  # в переменную Slov попадает слово которое ввел пользователь
Prefix=("$Slov")    # в этой переменной храниться слово для сравнения

for i in 1; do
if [[ "$Slov" = "$Prefix" ]]; then   #здесь мы сравниваем введенное слово с тем что должно быть
    #echo "cool"   # программа может продолжать работать
echo "Введите 0: программа выполнит все действия"
echo "Введите 1: программа выполнит только 1 действие - создаст с 100 файлов с рамдомными 4-ч значными числами"
echo "Введите 2: программа выполнит только 2 действие - выдаст сумму первых 50 чисел и вторых  50 чисел, а такще покажет какое из них самое большое"
echo "Введите 3: программа выполнит только 3 действие - программа скажет в каком файле лежит самое большое и самое маленькое число"
else
    #echo "ввод неверен"   # программа должна полностью остановиться
    exit 1  #в случае если слово введено неверно скрипт полность прекращает работу
fi
done

 echo -n "введит что хотите выполнить: "  #здесь мы вводим номер операции которую хотим выполнить
 read Nomer


function nomer_1 {
for i in {1..100};    #создаем файлы
do echo  $(( $RANDOM % 8999 + 1000 )) > /home/sm/2021-11-25/File$i; done  #рандомно создаем числа сохраняем их в вновь созданный файл
cat /home/sm/2021-11-25/* | while read y  #просмотр содержимого файлов из папки
do
echo "$y" >> /home/sm/2021-11-25/s    #выводит содержимое на экран, сохраняем все числа из созданных файлов File$i в
done
}
echo "$y"


function nomer_2 {
sum=0    #переменная для сложения всех чисел
g=0      #переменная для счетчика
A=0      #переменная в которой сохраняем сумму первой половины чисел
B=0      #переменнная в которой сохраняем сумму второй половины чисел
C=0      #переменная в которой сохраняется самое большое число
for i in `cat /home/sm/2021-11-25/s`;   # открываем файл s в котором содержатся числа
do
sum=$((sum+i))    #складываем все числа
let g+=1          #создали счетчик который увеличивается на +1 при каждом проходе цикла
if [[ $g -le 5 ]]; then   #условие в котором говорим что если счетчик меньше или равен 4,
        A=$(( $A + $i ))                                #тогда числа складваем в переменной A
elif [[ $g -ge 6 ]]; then #условие в котором говорим что если счетчик больше или равен 6,
        B=$(( $B + $i ))                                #тогда числа складваем в переменной B
fi
if [[ $A > $B ]]; then     #сравниваем суммы чисел из A и B и выводим если условие верное
C="$A" #самое большое число лежит в первой части"
elif [[ $B > $A ]]; then   #сравниваем суммы чисел из B и А и выводим если условие верное
C="$B" # самое большое число лежит во второй части "
fi
done
echo "$A сумма первых 50 чисел" "$B сумма вторых 50 чисел"
echo "$C самая большая сумма "
echo "$A сумма первых 50 чисел" "$B сумма вторых 50 чисел" >> /home/smu/2021-11-25/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).result
echo "$C самая большая сумма " >> /home/sm/2021-11-25/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).result   #выводим наибольшее число
}



function nomer_3 {
min=9999  #самое большое число которое может быть минимальным
max=0    #самое маленькое число которое может быть максимальным
for i in {1..100}
do
    value=`cat /home/sm/2021-11-25/File$i` #читаем поочереди все файлы
    if [[ "$value" -lt "$min" ]]    #ищем самое маленькое число
    then
        min=$value    #записываем в переменную самое маленькое число
        name="File$i" #находим файл в котором храниться самое маленькое число
    elif [[ "$value" -gt "$max" ]]  #ищем самое большое число
    then
        max=$value # записываем в переменную самое большое число
        name1="File$i" #находим файл в котором храниться самое большое число
    fi
done
echo "Минимальное значение $min найдено в файле $name"
echo "Максимальное значение $max найдено в файле $name1"
echo "Минимальное значение $min найдено в файле $name" >> /home/smursenko/2021-11-25/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).result
echo "Максимальное значение $max найдено в файле $name1" >> /home/smursenko/2021-11-25/$(date +%Y-%m-%d).result
}


function nomer_4 {
tar cfvz  /home/sm/$Prefix.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz  /home/smursenko/2021-11-25/* /home/smursenko/Podsget
}  #упаковывает все созданные файлы в один архив

function nomer_5 {
rm -f /home/sm/2021-11-25/*
} #удает все созданные файлы

function nomer_6 {
echo -n "введите PREFIX: "
read Slov  # в переменную Slov попадает слово которое ввел пользователь
Prefix=("$Slov")    # в этой переменной храниться слово для сравнения

for i in 1; do
if [[ "$Slov" = "$Prefix" ]]; then   #здесь мы сравниваем введенное слово с тем что должно быть
    #echo "cool"   # программа может продолжать работать
echo "Введите 0: программа выполнит все действия"
echo "Введите 1: программа выполнит только 1 действие - создаст с 100 файлов с рамдомными 4-ч значными числами"
echo "Введите 2: программа выполнит только 2 действие - выдаст сумму первых 50 чисел и вторых  50 чисел, а также покажет какое из этих чисел самое большое"
echo "Введите 3: программа выполнит только 3 действие - программа скажет в каком файле лежит самое большое и самое маленькое"
else
    #echo "ввод неверен"   # программа должна полностью остановиться
    exit 1  #в случае если слово введено неверно скрипт полностью прекращает работу
fi
done

  echo -n "введит что хотите выполнить: "  #здесь мы вводим номер операции которую хотим выполнить
  read Nomer
}
while true; do
case $Nomer in #Выполняем заданное действие

    "0")
        # Выполняем разом все действия
    nomer_1
    nomer_2
    nomer_3
    nomer_4
    nomer_5
    nomer_6
    ;;
   "1")

    nomer_1
    nomer_4
    nomer_5
    nomer_6
    ;;
   "2")

    nomer_1
    nomer_2
    nomer_6
    ;;
   "3")

    nomer_1
    nomer_3
    nomer_6
    ;;
esac
done
```

Не могу понять в чем ошибка, как исправить, все остальные действия(1,2,3) выполняются без ошибок.

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: напишите `set +x` в начале файла. Эта настройка включает вывод всех команд перед их исполнением. Посмотрите, во что превращается ваша ошибочная строчка при выполнении. Я проверил ваш скрипт у меня все работает. Правда, смущает то, что у вас везде разные пути: `/home/sm/`, `/home/smu/`, /home/smursenko`. Вы уж определитесь, где у вас лежат файлы.